# Is there any way to disable a bunch of form elements at once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, knockout.js

I'd like to disable a section of HTML form elements depending on some conditions.  This seems to be the ideal way to do that:

```
<fieldset disabled>
    <input value="one" />
    <input value="two" />
</fieldset>
```

Now, those two inputs are disabled.  However, this seems to be totally borked on IE8.  The inputs *appear* disabled but I can still type in them.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CvafW/) (Not as if JsFiddle actually *works* in IE8)

Is there a cross-browser solution for this problem, without adding *disabled* to every form element (which would complicate my script).  I could probably do something tricky like select the `<fieldset>` in jQuery, then `.each()` through all the form elements and disable them - however, I'm actually setting the `disabled` attribute using a Knockout binding so there's really no place to *add* such code.  My last resort is to use a custom Knockout binding that disables all the children too, but le sigh.

Comment: you could use an overlay to prevent clicking the inputs, but that wouldn't prevent tabbing to them, so you'd be in the same boat with the tabindex attribute. You could bind an event that prevents the keydown from happening, or even the focus event for that matter.

Comment: Yea, I'm not *hugely* into that solution.  Plus, integrating that into a Knockout template is still a hassle.  I'd rather just disable each element individually.

Comment: @MikeChristensen: The `fieldset` is not `borked` in IE8. It just is not fully supported. The `fieldset` is a HTML5 addition and IE8 does support very little HTML5 form elements. See the [**http://html5test.com results for IE8**](http://html5test.com/compare/browser/ie08.html) `fieldset` is only partially supported in IE8. As seen in the results `element attributes` are not supported. So you need most likely to come up with an alternative. An overlay, as suggested could be one of the options. Though there might be a polyfill which will work on fieldsets in IE8. Not 100% sure about that though.

Comment: @MikeChristensen: Another solution would be not to use any HTML5 elements at all if you must support IE8. I'm not trying to be smart. I'm only suggesting it as an option. Also I have to admit, this is strange as according to the above test results for HTML5 I linked in the previous comment the `disabled attribute` is suppose to be supported in IE8. The same is shown when going to [**http://html5test.com/**](http://html5test.com/) on IE8 which runs the HTML5 tests, showing the same results. Strange indeed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short: **No**. The reason behind this is because the lack of support in IE8 and the `disabled` attribute on the `fieldset` element.

[Source](http://www.standardista.com/html5/html5-web-forms/#fieldset_element)

> In IE7 and IE8, the attribute only disables form elements in the
>   < legend >.

I'm afraid you should look for a custom solution like the answers from other users / your own custom binding.

Comment: +1 for the source. I was looking at [**http://html5test.com/compare/browser/ie08.html**](http://html5test.com/compare/browser/ie08.html) and in there is stated the `disabled attribute` was supported, though `element attributes` were not. Very confusing. I shall keep a note of that link of yours.

Answer (score 11):

Ok, I've come up with a Knockout.js specific implementation that hopefully will help some other people in the same boat.  This solution could probably be adapted for other solutions and platforms with a little effort.

First, I created a Knockout binding:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.allowEdit = {
   init: function(element, valueAccessor)
   {
      if(!valueAccessor())
      {
         element.disabled = true;
         element.readOnly = true;

         if(element.tagName === 'FIELDSET')
         {
            $(':input', element).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
         }
      }
   }
};
```

Note, you'd have to implement the `update` method too if you wanted to allow changes to this binding.  I didn't have this requirement.

You could then use the binding as such:

```
<fieldset data-bind="allowEdit: someExpression">
   <input value="One" />
   <input value="Two" />
</fieldset>
```

Comment: `$('fieldset :input').attr('disabled', '');` and `$('fieldset :input').removeAttr('disabled');` seems to include textarea and select.  You might not need to specify them all separately: http://jsfiddle.net/CvafW/1/ Not sure if that is the same in all browsers though.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl - Yup, right you are on that..  Updating my code.

Comment: oh and off course +1, seeing that this is a solution which seems to work for you but also will most likely be useful to future users battling with similar issues using `knockoutJS`.

Answer (score 2):

Solution using jQuery:

```
var disabledFiedset=$('fieldset[disabled]');
$('input',disabledFiedset).attr('disabled','disabled');
```

Comment: `+1` since I used part of your solution.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do something similar using an observable in my model called editable and then in my input I used a `data-bind="enable: editable”` and this totally works in IE 7, 8 and 9.

Comment: Sure, but you'd have to put this on every form field.

Comment: Yes but it is all controlled by one observable.

Answer (score 0):

Give the id to your fieldset tag(or u can also use tag name directly in jquery code) & use following code to make all the fields disable in that fieldset using jquery.

$("#fieldset id" or "fieldset").children().attr("disabled", "disabled");